# google translate api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to use Google Translate API for translating English to Spanish.  I want to know if there is any API for this as I did some searches for this and all I can find is trash.  Maybe I am not searching well.

Please let me know any useful links regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two Google Translate APIs – [version 1](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/getting_started.html) and [version 2](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html) .

Comment: @Radix - And they aren't trash either :)

Comment: i tried to access version 1 with the help of this link https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v1? its showing me page not found and same goes for version 2

Comment: @Radix: I'm using a app named Translator+ and it can translate from/to many languages including Spanish. The author said that he used Google Translate service. You can find more info here http://www.ithinkdiff.net

Comment: @Tiendq: can u provide me the entire link, it would be very helpful

Comment: @Radix: I'm not sure what link you were asking for. I posted it, didn't I? If you want a specific page in that site, here you are http://ithinkdiff.net/reference/translator-free/